# How might one be able to properly use Recovery Mode on my Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-os, recovery

I was wondering how it might be possible to properly use Recovery Mode on my Chromebook. Whenever I went into Recovery Mode, the main screen was always telling me; "Use an 8GB or more USB." But it never told me how or what do download. Just "Use an 8GB or more USB." Would anybody know how to properly download and use Recovery Mode and the necessary information needed to use it?

Comment: One question per post please. Also, what is telling you to use an 8GB USB, and what research have you done?

Comment: I was unfortunately not able to do any research because of web restrictions, and I will limit to one post. And it was the opening screen for Recovery Mode that was telling me this.

Comment: You misread me. One question per post. It is OK to have more than one post, but each post should have just one question in it. Also, we are not the work around for running your own internet search.

Comment: Is it perhaps the case that you are trying to reset a managed Chromebook in order to remove controls on it?

Comment: Maybe, to your third comment.   Also, I am sorry if it bothers you that I have two questions on my post. I am new to the system and did not [until now] realize that I could remove the second question. I apologize again.

Comment: We don't assist with removing legitimate controls on devices here. The correct way to do this is to contact the owner and ask them to remove the controls.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-collect-these-devices%2Cstep-download-a-new-copy-of-the-os

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the USB drive using the [Chrome Recovery Utility](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromebook-recovery-utili/pocpnlppkickgojjlmhdmidojbmbodfm) or other such tool (there are tools for other platforms available, you may have to request or search for them through their Discord server).  You will also need to select the appropriate model for the recovery image, which appears to be a whole lot more complicated than it should be.  I forget the URL, but once again the Discord is the go-to if you have trouble with this, there is a site that they use to lookup the proper recovery by your board's model (you can check your specs by going to `chrome://system`.

I suggest you post a separate question for your other inquiry.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: I tried to use the Chrome Recovery Utility, but web restrictions disabled it. :( I will keep trying.

Comment: Thanks again for your help anyways